# how to change Application language on run time using Two Button in iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios4

i am building up a project  in ios platform and want to use two language in this  application 
and also want  . the user can change the language on Runtime suppose we can take two language button  button 1 for english and button 2 for german and  the user can change  the application language at  any time by using these button .  any help or tutorials

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you have created localizations for English and German, your app will use the language selected in Settings (this is the preferred option).

If you want to set the language directly from your application:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

will set the language for your application only to English (for German, I assume the key is "de").  You should also:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

This will not take effect until your application restarts.

Comment: :This is efficient way . But you have to restart application which is not user friendly.

Comment: Correct.  But there is no way that Apple allows to change the language without restarting the app.  I imagine you could do it programmatically be reimplementing localization yourself, but that's not very appealing.

Comment: Yes Actually I was also came across the same problem but requirement is like in application the user should able to change the language at that time I didn't have any ways so I have followed the following tutorial.

Comment: Seems to work in iOS 7.1 simulator. No need to restart

Comment: iOS 8 didn't work until restart. But this is for testing, so restarting is ok, in fact, I added an exit(1) to force-crash the app after changing the language, hacky, but works.

Comment: I did the same (exit), but this was in an enterprise app.  Might not be acceptable for the App Store.

Comment: @PaulLynch. Is there any option without restarting the app . Please help me

Comment: Only by managing your own language lookup. There are several examples given in other answers.  But to switch languages automatically requires a restart.

Answer (score 3):

Have a class "LanguageUtils" with that method :

```
- (NSString *) localizedString:(NSString *)key
{
    if (self.currentLanguage == nil) {
        self.currentLanguage = @"en";
    }

    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[self.currentLanguage lowercaseString] ofType:@"lproj"];
    NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    return [languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil];
}
```

And the property NSString currentLanguage.

Then in your .pch do :

```
#undef NSLocalizedString
#define NSLocalizedString(key, _comment) [[Language sharedInstance] localizedString:key]
```

Works like a charm and you can redefine the current language at runtime.

Just keep in mind that your view should be refreshed by yourself. It won't automatically do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a solution that allows you to use `NSLocalizedString`. I create a category of `NSBundle` call `NSBundle+RunTimeLanguage`. The interface is like this.

```
// NSBundle+RunTimeLanguage.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface NSBundle (RunTimeLanguage)
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) [[NSBundle mainBundle] runTimeLocalizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
- (NSString *)runTimeLocalizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName;
@end
```

The implementation is like this.

```
// NSBundle+RunTimeLanguage.m
#import "NSBundle+RunTimeLanguage.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation NSBundle (RunTimeLanguage)

- (NSString *)runTimeLocalizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSString *path= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[appDelegate languageCode] ofType:@"lproj"];
    NSBundle *languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    NSString *localizedString=[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:key table:nil];
    return localizedString;
}
@end
```

Than just add import `NSBundle+RunTimeLanguage.h` into the files that use `NSLocalizedString`.

As you can see I store my languageCode in a property of `AppDelegate`.  This could be stored anywhere you'd like.

This only thing I don't like about it is a Warning that `NSLocalizedString` marco redefined.  Perhaps someone could help me fix this part.

Comment: You can add a `#undef NSLocalizedString` before to get rid of the redefinition warning

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://aggressive-mediocrity.blogspot.in/2010/03/custom-localization-system-for-your.html) is very good and the language is changed within the app and also when device language changes. I used this in many apps.

For localization we generally use

```
 NSLocalizedString(@"hello",@"Hello World");
```

in the custom implementation they have something similar like this

```
 AMLocalizedString(@"hello",@"Hello World");
```

Comment: This method has the disadvantage that the `genstrings` command doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

Here is demo tutorial

https://github.com/object2dot0/Advance-Localization-in-ios-apps

Just remove

```
 [self dealloc];
```

from

```
 -(IBAction) languageSelection:(id)sender
```

so it wont be crash!!! enjoy!

Comment: does this work with storyboard, means if we want to change the text of uielement on storyboard (or xib) can we able to change the text to new set language

Answer (score 0):

You have to use localization for this . Just store the key and value in side localizable.string and load the appropriate .string file as per your requirement .
You can refer following tutorial for this :
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 2.0 version**
We can do this on run time without restarting the app in Swift 2.0 as follows

Make a function within a class, lets say **LanguageManager** is the name of the class

```
class LanguageManager
{

    static let sharedInstance =  LanguageManager()

    //Make a function for Localization. Language Code is the one which we will be deciding on button click.
    func LocalizedLanguage(key:String,languageCode:String)->String{

        //Make sure you have Localizable bundles for specific languages.
        var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(languageCode, ofType: "lproj")

        //Check if the path is nil, make it as "" (empty path)
        path = (path != nil ? path:"")

        let languageBundle:NSBundle!

        if(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path!)){
            languageBundle = NSBundle(path: path!)
            return languageBundle!.localizedStringForKey(key, value: "", table: nil)
        }else{
            // If path not found, make English as default
            path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("en", ofType: "lproj")
            languageBundle = NSBundle(path: path!)
           return languageBundle!.localizedStringForKey(key, value: "", table: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

How to Use this.
Now Assume you have two Languages for the application (English and Spanish)
English - **en**
Spanish - **es**
[image]

Suppose you have to place something for a label

```
//LOGIN_LABEL_KEY is the one that you will define in Localizable.strings for Login label text
 logInLabel.text = LanguageManager.sharedInstance.LocalizedLanguage("LOGIN_LABEL_KEY", languageCode: "es")

//This will use the Spanish version of the text. 
//"es" is the language code which I have hardcoded here. We can use a variable or some stored value in UserDefaults which will change on Button Click and will be passed in loginLabel
```

For more info on language codes see this link below
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html

or

http://www.ibabbleon.com/iOS-Language-Codes-ISO-639.html