# I want change my own app language on button click in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

```
if(btn.tag==1)
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
}else{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ar", nil]  forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
}
```

but it's not changing language for the first time first I select language and restart the app then it change the language but not change for the very first time

Thanks

Comment: where you are writing this kind of code

Comment: on button click I have two button and given tag 1 and 2 1 tag button for english and 2 tag button for arabic

Comment: I think problem for giving Tag so pls concentrate on Tag value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change the language, once it's set. Thats why you get it right, after the next time you launch the app.

If you already knew this, then please explain your question a bit more.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032207/how-to-change-application-language-on-run-time-using-two-button-in-iphone-sdk look at this link. You can change the language on run time as well.